# ValueError: Extra data when sending data from client to server

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, json-deserialization

I am using a client-server socket connection in python as shown below

[image]

client-side code is given below

```
   data_tuple = [client_id,client_req_time,type_of_VM_requested,service_time]  # final tuple of data that is sent by client
   data_string = json.dumps(data_tuple)  # data serialized
   clientSocket.send(str(data_string))  # sending data to server
```

Server-side code is as follows

```
while True:   # extra while is created  so that server keeps running
    running = True
    clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()  # accept a connection from client
    print ("\n connected to Client Simulator  at " + ServerIP + " on Port # " + str(Server_port))
    while running:
        receivedData = clientsocket.recv(1024)
        # ------------------ parsing the client request -----------------------#
        if receivedData:
            client_tuple = json.loads(receivedData)  # data de-serialized
            client_id = client_tuple[0]
            arrival_time = str(client_tuple[1])  # from unicode to str
            type_of_vm_requested = str(client_tuple[2])  # from unicode to str
            service_time = str(client_tuple[3])  # from unicode to str
```

The issue is that this program works for a while like after third client it gives error as shown below

```
 The server is waiting for Client requests...
 connected to Client Simulator  at 127.0.0.1 on Port # 9988
 Request Received : client id = 1 , Arrival_time = 2018-01-08 20:29:10:093  , Service_time = 12 sec, VM type  = vkey_type_B Looking for a requested VM...  VM is available  VM allocation is done and VM started successfully  Database Allocation update successfully
 Request Received : client id = 2 , Arrival_time = 2018-01-08 20:29:10:859  , Service_time = 8 sec, VM type  = vkey_type_B Looking for a requested VM...  VM is available  VM allocation is done and VM started successfully  Database Allocation update successfully
 Request Received : client id = 3 , Arrival_time = 2018-01-08 20:29:12:394  , Service_time = 24 sec, VM type  = vkey_type_B Looking for a requested VM...  VM is available  VM allocation is done and VM started successfully  Database Allocation update successfully Extra data: line 1 column 50 - line 1 column 294 (char 49 - 293) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D_pool_logic.py", line 609, in <module>
    run_pool(new_session)                                               # calling the main poolmanager function   File "D_pool_logic.py", line 25, in run_pool
    start_client_request_handling_server(session)  # starts request listening server , as our main server is up and running   File "D_pool_logic.py", line 444, in start_client_request_handling_server
    client_tuple = json.loads(receivedData)  # data de-serialized   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s))) ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 50 - line 1 column 294 (char 49 - 293)
```

The output of `print data_string` at client-side is

```
[1, "2018-01-08 21:12:01:393", "vkey_type_A", 7]
[2, "2018-01-08 21:12:04:669", "vkey_type_A", 17]
[3, "2018-01-08 21:12:18:777", "vkey_type_B", 11]
[4, "2018-01-08 21:12:30:748", "vkey_type_A", 19]
[5, "2018-01-08 21:12:34:327", "vkey_type_A", 17]
[6, "2018-01-08 21:13:21:729", "vkey_type_A", 18]
[7, "2018-01-08 21:13:29:445", "vkey_type_A", 7]
```

The output of `print client_tuple` at server-side is

```
[1, u'2018-01-08 21:12:01:393', u'vkey_type_A', 7]
[2, u'2018-01-08 21:12:04:669', u'vkey_type_A', 17] 
[3, u'2018-01-08 21:12:18:777', u'vkey_type_B', 11]
```

after 3rd request, it gave error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B_VM_creater.py", line 331, in <module>
    start_server(new_session)  # starts request listening server , as our main server is up and running
  File "B_VM_creater.py", line 227, in start_server
    client_tuple = json.loads(receivedData)  # data de-serialized
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 16 - line 1 column 31 (char 15 - 30)
```

Comment: What is the value of `receivedData` when the error occurs? Maybe you're only getting a portion of the data in that read, or part of the next json string? Just because you're sending the data as separate strings, doesn't necessarily mean you will receive them the same way.

Answer (score 0):

the problem has been solved by using `pickle.dumps()` while sending data and `pickle.load()` while receiving data

at Client-side, the code is

```
data_tuple = [client_id,client_req_time,type_of_VM_requested,service_time]  # final tuple of data that is sent by client
data_string = pickle.dumps(data_tuple)  # data serialized
clientSocket.send(data_string)  # sending data to server
```

at Server-side, the code is

```
if receivedData:
                client_tuple = pickle.loads(receivedData)  # data de-serialized
                client_id = client_tuple[0]
                arrival_time = str(client_tuple[1])  # from unicode to str , as timestamp is a string not a number
                type_of_vm_requested = str(client_tuple[2])  # from unicode to str
                service_time = int(client_tuple[3])  # from unicode to str
```